# How to display modified text from data member in :items object array for item-title in v-select (Vuetify) dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuetify.js, v-select

I am new to Vue and I am currently working with Vuetify to build dropdown "v-select".

If there is a way, that will be great! Otherwise, I am thinking of creating new array and covert data for some members in objects and copy them to new array and set that array as :items in v-select.

Here is my code

```
<v-select 
    label="Select a permission to copy"
    variant="underlined"
    item-title="resource"
    no-data-text="No permission to choose from"
    :items="permissionsToCopy"
    v-model="selectedPermissionToCopy"
    return-object
>
</v-select>
```

for `resource` in `item-title`, i want to display like
if it is `resource == company_user_licence` then I want to display `item-title` to be `Licence Permission: User`

I have looked for ways to customize template for item-title, so far i have found ways to make templates for item-text and item-value, not item-title.

Please let me know if the question is not clear or need more details. Thank you!

Comment: `:item-title="someFunction"` and have `someFunction` do the required logic?

Comment: Hi Jaromanda, yes I thought about that but I decided to do `template v-slot:item` inside `v-select` instead. thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `v-list-item` component to customize `item-title`:

```
<template>
    <v-select label="User" :items="items" item-title="name">
        <template v-slot:item="{ props, item }">
            <v-list-item
                v-bind="props"
                :title="`${item.title} - ${item.value}`"
            ></v-list-item>
        </template>
    </v-select>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data: () => ({
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'John',
                    department: 'Marketing',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Jane',
                    department: 'Engineering',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    department: 'Sales',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Janet',
                    department: 'Engineering',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Jake',
                    department: 'Marketing',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Jack',
                    department: 'Sales',
                },
            ],
        }),
    }
    </script>
```

if you want to implement more than one line logic you can change it `:title='myCustomTitle()'` to a method

Answer (score 0):

This is what i had to come up with.

I also had to add `vslot:selection` on top of @Mojtaba answer or it won't show what i have selected. Thanks for answering!

Just documenting here in case if someone is looking for answers similar to mine.

```html
<v-select 
    label="Select a permission to copy"
    variant="underlined"
    no-data-text="No permission to choose from"
    :items="permissionsToCopy"
    v-model="selectedPermissionToCopy"
    return-object
>
    <template v-slot:selection="{item, props}">
        <v-list-item v-bind="props" style="padding: 0;" :title="convertToReadableText(item.value)"></v-list-item>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item="{item, props}">
        <v-list-item v-bind="props" :title="convertToReadableText(item.value)"></v-list-item>
    </template>
</v-select>
```